# Animation in Jetpack Compose (AnimatedVisibility) not working at all for me?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I want to animate some text's visibility to not just appear/disappear but to slide in/out in Jetpack Compose Android app that I'm building.

I just literally copy-pasted that little code snippet from developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation and it does not work:

```
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val density = LocalDensity.current
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = visible,
    enter = slideInVertically {
        // Slide in from 40 dp from the top.
        with(density) { -40.dp.roundToPx() }
    } + expandVertically(
        // Expand from the top.
        expandFrom = Alignment.Top
    ) + fadeIn(
        // Fade in with the initial alpha of 0.3f.
        initialAlpha = 0.3f
    ),
    exit = slideOutVertically() + shrinkVertically() + fadeOut()
) {
    Text("Hello", Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(200.dp))
}
```

It simply does not animate, the text gets shown/hidden without any animation.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

I guess I can't paste my whole app here, as it would be silly, it would be nice of Google to give us a Jetpack Compose Playground of sorts, to be able to practice and test code there...

Comment: I tried your code and its animating properly, so its hard to guess what's wrong in it, maybe its has something to do with  its height or the height of where it animates, the bigger it is the faster it will transition, or maybe the phone's developer settings has animations set to disabled, just guessing

Comment: I dunno where was the problem, but after a lot of rewriting of my composable functions and refactoring stuff, it just started to work nicely, just ignore this whole post, sorry

Comment: You were using a state variable with the overload which uses a regular boolean to activate animation, there is a version of AnimatedVisibility that has "visibilityState" as its first parameter, could that have been your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if AnimatedVisibility can be used without a state variable var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) } ?

Comment: @ArthurKasparian I had a similar issue your comment made it work. I am new to compose and I wanted to run the animation as soon as it is added to the tree and visibilitystate is the right approach.

Comment: @anshul it actually is not (if I understood your case correctly), MutableTransitionState is what you should be using when animating visibility on entrance, you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#enter-exit-transition), the codeblock under the transitions table!

Comment: @ArthurKasparian Sorry if I confused you. Yes, I am using MutableTransitionState in my case. I meant that earlier I was using AnimatedVisibility with a visible parameter which did not work. then I figured out that I should have been using AnimatedVIsibility with visibilityState as a param by passing MutableTransitionState and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was just facing the same problem. No animations working at all. Additionally, I had a strong feeling I did not change anything.

**In my case, it was actually caused by the developer settings on that particular target device.**

**All animations were actually disabled by my colleague.**

We are sharing the development devices, so I did not know someone did it. As it is not any obvious, I wasted a lot of time on it too.

**After re-enabling it, all animations started to work normally.**

Side note (I know it does not relate to the topic, please do not beat me; I have no such experience myself, but I mention it as it could be eventually useful information for others too): He explained to me something like that he uses the Espresso framework for the UI testing, and that the Espresso is somehow stupid, and that the animations in the app are actually causing the tests to be unstable: Introducing the race conditions, by simulating taps on UI elements which are potentially (that is the race condition) still being animated in; rather than doing sleeps in the app, he prefers to disable the animations at all.

Answer (score -2):

Use visibleState param instead of visible into AnimatedVisibility().